# How to install WebSphere 7.0 Trial

Tags: websphere

I have successfully installed WAS ND 8.5.5 trial version but have been asked to certify an app against WAS 7.

Because there is now WAS 9, I think the direct link to the 7 repo has been removed from the public site for Devs: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/WAS_traditional_for_Developers

Anyone know how I can add the repo for WAS 7 to the installation manager so I can certify my app against it?

Answer (score 0):

The [End of Market date for WAS 7](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycleapp/PLCDetail.wss?q45=U014343F68568M71) was Dec 16th 2016, and it is going out of service on Apr 30th 2018.

So you can no longer obtain new copies of WAS 7 (nor would you want to, I hope).